# Uso do Eloquent hasManyThrough

Tags: laravel, query, laravel-eloquent

```
    // Modelo Cliente
    public function plano()
    {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Plano', 'App\Plano_cliente','cliente_id','id','plano_id');
     }

    //Modelo Plano
    public function cliente()
    {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Cliente', 'App\Plano_cliente','plano_id','id','cliente_id');
     }
    // Modelo Plano_cliente
    protected function cliente(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cliente')->withPivot('cliente_id', 'id');
    }
        protected function plano(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Plano')->withPivot('plano_id', 'id');
    }
```

Estes são os três modelos 
Cliente ->  plano_cliente <- Plano

Quando faço a consulta:
 Cliente::with(plano)->get();

retorna no resultset todos os clientes mas só o primeiro plano de cada
Podem ter varios planos cada cliente

Answer (score 1):

**Modelo Cliente**

```
    public function plano()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Plano', 'plano_cliente','cliente_id','plano_id');
    }
```

**Modelo plano**

```
     public function cliente()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cliente', 'plano_cliente','plano_id','cliente_id');
    }
```

**Modelo plano_cliente**

```
    protected function cliente(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cliente');
    }
    protected function plano(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Plano');
    }
```

Assim deu tudo certo

Comment: Exato e lembre-se que pode user um *->has('plano')* ou um *->with('plano')*, sendo o primeiro se trará no objeto o que tiver um plano e no segundo todos com os planos.